# What is the correct way to load this XML file in this weird format?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-namespaces

I've encountered an XML file that I can't read correctly. I know it's a good file; I'm just doing something stupid.

Here is an example of the XML:

```
    - <Army xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <ArmyName>Simple Army</ArmyName> 
  <Description>A file for test loading.</Description> 
  <LastId>2</LastId> 
- <Units xmlns:a="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ModelLib">
- <a:Unit>
  <a:Accuracy i:nil="true" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" /> 
  <a:Ammunition>30</a:Ammunition> 
  <a:CO>-1</a:CO> 
  <a:CloseCombat>1</a:CloseCombat> 
  <a:CommandLevel>1</a:CommandLevel> 
  <a:GetsFirstShotBonus>true</a:GetsFirstShotBonus> 
  <a:HQ>true</a:HQ> 
  <a:ID>0</a:ID> 
  <a:KStrength>1</a:KStrength> 
  <a:Leadership>50</a:Leadership> 
  <a:Morale>50</a:Morale> 
  <a:Name>General Smith</a:Name> 
  <a:Quality>50</a:Quality> 
  <a:Range>150</a:Range> 
  <a:Reload>30</a:Reload> 
  <a:Shooting>1</a:Shooting> 
  <a:SkirmishOption>Never</a:SkirmishOption> 
  <a:Strength>1000</a:Strength> 
- <a:Subordinates>
- <a:Unit>
- <a:Accuracy xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  <b:double>100</b:double> 
  </a:Accuracy>
  <a:Ammunition>30</a:Ammunition> 
  <a:CO>0</a:CO> 
  <a:CloseCombat>1</a:CloseCombat> 
  <a:CommandLevel>2</a:CommandLevel> 
  <a:GetsFirstShotBonus>true</a:GetsFirstShotBonus> 
  <a:HQ>true</a:HQ> 
  <a:ID>1</a:ID> 
  <a:KStrength>1</a:KStrength> 
  <a:Leadership>50</a:Leadership> 
  <a:Morale>50</a:Morale> 
  <a:Name>Major Disaster</a:Name> 
  <a:Quality>50</a:Quality> 
  <a:Range>150</a:Range> 
  <a:Reload>30</a:Reload> 
  <a:Shooting>1</a:Shooting> 
  <a:SkirmishOption>Never</a:SkirmishOption> 
  <a:Strength>1000</a:Strength> 
- <a:Subordinates>
- <a:Unit>
- <a:Accuracy xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
  <b:double>1</b:double> 
  <b:double>1</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.996</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.995</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.993</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.991</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.989</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.986</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.983</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.979</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.977</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.974</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.972</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.969</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.965</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.962</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.96</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.956</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.95</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.945</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.938</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.931</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.923</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.912</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.9</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.885</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.869</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.846</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.827</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.804</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.781</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.76</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.737</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.713</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.688</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.66</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.631</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.603</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.576</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.547</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.52</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.494</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.467</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.441</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.42</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.4</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.383</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.364</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.343</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.322</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.301</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.281</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.265</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.25</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.233</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.216</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.202</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.19</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.177</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.167</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.155</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.148</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.139</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.132</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.126</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.118</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.113</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.107</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.103</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.1</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.095</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.09</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.085</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.083</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.079</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.076</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.073</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.07</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.067</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.065</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.064</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.062</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.058</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.056</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.052</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.05</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.048</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.046</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.043</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.04</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.037</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.034</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.031</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.029</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.027</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.022</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.021</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.016</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.011</b:double> 
  <b:double>0.003</b:double> 
  </a:Accuracy>
  <a:Ammunition>30</a:Ammunition> 
  <a:CO>1</a:CO> 
  <a:CloseCombat>1</a:CloseCombat> 
  <a:CommandLevel>3</a:CommandLevel> 
  <a:GetsFirstShotBonus>true</a:GetsFirstShotBonus> 
  <a:HQ>false</a:HQ> 
  <a:ID>2</a:ID> 
  <a:KStrength>1</a:KStrength> 
  <a:Leadership>50</a:Leadership> 
  <a:Morale>50</a:Morale> 
  <a:Name>Captain Infantry</a:Name> 
  <a:Quality>50</a:Quality> 
  <a:Range>150</a:Range> 
  <a:Reload>30</a:Reload> 
  <a:Shooting>1</a:Shooting> 
  <a:SkirmishOption>Never</a:SkirmishOption> 
  <a:Strength>1000</a:Strength> 
  <a:Subordinates /> 
  <a:Type>Infantry</a:Type> 
  </a:Unit>
  </a:Subordinates>
  <a:Type>HeadQuarters</a:Type> 
  </a:Unit>
  </a:Subordinates>
  <a:Type>HeadQuarters</a:Type> 
  </a:Unit>
  </Units>
  </Army>
```

I'm trying to read it with this code (updated as per suggestion, below):

```
                XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
                xmlDoc.Load(ScenarioFilename);
                XmlNamespaceManager nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xmlDoc.NameTable);

                nsm.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ModelLib");
                var nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Army/Units/d:Unit", nsm);
                bool tempval;

                foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
                {
                    tempHQ = node.SelectSingleNode("d:HQ", nsm).InnerText;
                    tempID = node.SelectSingleNode("d:ID", nsm).InnerText;
                    Boolean.TryParse(tempHQ, out tempval);
                    RedArmy[Int32.Parse(tempID)].IsHQ = tempval;
                }// foreach
```

But, nodelist returns 0 items.
Among the things that are confusing me is when to use 'd:' or 'a:' in the read. What is the rule?

Comment: Do you particularly need to use `XmlDocument`? While I'm sure this can be done, the newer LINQ to XML is a much easier API to use - particularly for namespaces.

Comment: No. Not familiar with LINQ to XML.

Comment: There's nothing weird about the format, but you shouldn't be posting screenshots of XML if you'd like better answers verified against your example.

Comment: Please copy and paste the text of your XML instead of posting a screenshot. We strongly discourage screenshots of text here. At least one of the downvotes is probably over that, if not all of them. People want to be able to search and copy your code and data (I always test my answers; do you expect me to retype your XML?). Since you apologize for it being a screenshot, people might get the idea that you understand that it's wrong, but you don't care.

Comment: Including the XML as an image prevents people from copy/pasting it for testing to help solve the problem, and expecting us to go somewhere else to get it is not reasonable. Please read [mcve] and come back to [edit] your post to provide all relevant information here in the question itself.

Comment: I've added a link to the XML file.

Comment: I've created the absolute barebones Mininimal Complete and Verifiable example XML file and inserted above. This is the complete XML file and the nodelist for HQ should return '2'.

Comment: Your XML is nowhere near minimal.  Your C# is not complete.  You've squandered the attention of multiple resources who could have helped you many times over by now had you provided an actual [mcve].  Moving on.  Good luck.

Comment: The XML here is not valid. I suspect that's because you've copied and pasted it from a browser, which adds the +/- devices. Would you repair it? Also, if you can remove various duplicated rows, that will make it more minimal. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`Army` and `Units` are in no namespace, yet you're selecting them as if it were in the `"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ModelLib"` namespace (prefixed via `d`).

Change

```
var nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/d:Army/d:Units/d:Unit", nsm);
```

to

```
var nodeList = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("/Army/Units/d:Unit", nsm);
```

You then go on to switch the namespace prefix to `a`:

```
  tempHQ = node.SelectSingleNode("a:HQ", nsm).InnerText;
  tempID = node.SelectSingleNode("a:ID", nsm).InnerText;
```

Those too should be as originally defined, `d`:

```
nsm.AddNamespace("d", "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/ModelLib");
```

(Or switch all to `a` as the XML uses.  Either way, be consistent.)

Comment: Just modified code above and in file and nodelist is still returning a count of '0'; which is wrong.

Comment: The changes described in this answer are definitely necessary, but since you didn't include a [mcve] with XML as text rather than as an image, I couldn't confirm that the changes were sufficient.

Comment: Okay, it's a big file. I'll upload to my site and post a link.

Comment: I've uploaded the file and put a link to it in the question.

Comment: No, first prune it down the ***minimal*** example that still exhibits the problem.  That's the **M** in [mcve].   Yes, it's a bit of work, but it's your responsibility, not ours:  (1) Nobody should have to wade through excessively large examples, and (2) Your question should stand on its own for future readers' benefit regardless of link integrity.